# What are the valid types for the type parameter in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new(type)?

Tags: python, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to use python to create nodes in the compositor.  Right now I want to create an ID Mask node, but there will eventually be others.

If I create an ID Mask node via the UI and ask the python console what is C.scene.node_tree.nodes.active.type it tells me 'ID_MASK', but if I C.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('ID_MASK') I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Error: Node type ID_MASK undefined
```

How do I learn the proper values for the type parameter for node_tree.nodes.new(type) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2.68 the [API doc for Nodes.new(type)](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.Nodes.html#bpy.types.Nodes) states "Type of node to add (Warning: should be same as node.bl_idname, not node.type!)"

```
>>> [n.bl_idname for n in D.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes]
['ShaderNodeOutputMaterial', 'ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse', 'NodeReroute']
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct type for this would be: `'CompositorNodeIDMask'`.

Too create a new ID Mask node the line would be :  `C.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeIDMask')`

If this is confusing, at least they have a pattern so you have `'CompositorNode'`or`'ShaderNode'`or`'TextureNode'` plus the node type like `'ShaderNode'+'ObjectInfo'`.

For the full list of node types see these links: [shader nodes](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.ShaderNode.html#bpy.types.ShaderNode), [compositor nodes](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.CompositorNode.html) and [texture nodes](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.TextureNode.html)

Comment: It turns out those links are not the FULL list.  There are things like NodeReroute too.

Answer (score 1):

type(bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active)

class 'bpy.types.CompositorNodeIDMask'

```
import bpy
ntype = str(type(bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active))
nodetype = ntype.rsplit('.')[2][:-2]
print (nodetype)
```