# procedural texture driven by image texture? Possible?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, objects, procedural

I am just messing around and trying to make some kind of object that has a bunch of hearts on it. I have an image of a simple heart and I tried mixing it with a checkerboard texture and it wasnt working. I'm just making sure I'm not wasting my time and trying to do something that isnt possible. I'm still very new to blender!!

Comment: Please show a sketch of what you are trying to get.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102692/randomly-populating-procedural-shape-or-image-texture-in-cycles