Creating a texture with random overlapping circles of different colors
I want to procedurally create a texture like the following, made of randomly-placed circles, all the same radius, with random grayscale colors applied. Ideally repeating (this one isn't). Ideally, NOT anti-aliased. Is it possible?

The little experimentation I've done is to create a white texture with circular alpha (setting alpha to Channel Packed, so the RGB channels aren't tainted), and mix that white color down to black based on a factor. I can modify the UV coords for a single image to scale it down and place it. And I can composite two RGBA images in a layered fashion.

What I'm missing is:

How to calculate multiple random numbers in a shader
How to make n copies of an image in a shader, and layer their results


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102692/randomly-populating-procedural-shape-or-image-texture-in-cycles

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you for that. Seems at first like a slam-dunk duplicate. Unfortunately, the accepted answer no longer works (and has a 404 link to background info, and relies on an abandoned add-on), and the second answer appears—and I'm only a few minutes into looking into it—to produce black/white only (a single mask). But, the concepts of generating random numbers via noise are spot on, and hopefully more will be applicable, too.
